# Apache Geode Start a Locator and a Server Inside Java Application

Tags: java, geode

I'm new to Apache Geode and trying to run a locator and a server inside my java application but there is an exception when I start the app. Here is the code I am using for starting locator and server:

```
public static void locatorStarter() {
    LocatorLauncher locatorLauncher = new LocatorLauncher.Builder()
            .setMemberName("locator1")
            .setPort(13334)
            .build();
    locatorLauncher.start();
}

public static void serverStarter() {
    ServerLauncher serverLauncher = new ServerLauncher.Builder()
            .setMemberName("server1")
            .setServerPort(40404)
            .build();
    serverLauncher.start();
}
```

When I call these methods from the main function I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: A connection to a distributed system already exists in this VM.  It has the following configuration:
  ack-severe-alert-threshold="0"
  ack-wait-threshold="15"
  archive-disk-space-limit="0"
  archive-file-size-limit="0"
  async-distribution-timeout="0"
  async-max-queue-size="8"
  async-queue-timeout="60000"
  bind-address=""
  cache-xml-file="" ***(wanted "cache.xml")***
  cluster-configuration-dir=""
  cluster-ssl-ciphers="any"
  cluster-ssl-enabled="false"
  cluster-ssl-keystore=""
  cluster-ssl-keystore-password=""
  cluster-ssl-keystore-type=""
  cluster-ssl-protocols="any"
  cluster-ssl-require-authentication="true"
  cluster-ssl-truststore=""
  cluster-ssl-truststore-password=""
  conflate-events="server"
  conserve-sockets="true"
  delta-propagation="true"
  deploy-working-dir="C:\Users\Fatih Barmanbay\IdeaProjects\geodelucene"
  disable-auto-reconnect="false"
  disable-tcp="false"
  distributed-system-id="-1"
  distributed-transactions="false"
  durable-client-id=""
  durable-client-timeout="300"
  enable-cluster-configuration="true"
  enable-network-partition-detection="true"
  enable-time-statistics="false"
  enforce-unique-host="false"
  gateway-ssl-ciphers="any"
  gateway-ssl-enabled="false"
  gateway-ssl-keystore=""
  gateway-ssl-keystore-password=""
  gateway-ssl-keystore-type=""
  gateway-ssl-protocols="any"
  gateway-ssl-require-authentication="true"
  gateway-ssl-truststore=""
  gateway-ssl-truststore-password=""
  groups=""
  http-service-bind-address=""
  http-service-port="7070"
  http-service-ssl-ciphers="any"
  http-service-ssl-enabled="false"
  http-service-ssl-keystore=""
  http-service-ssl-keystore-password=""
  http-service-ssl-keystore-type=""
  http-service-ssl-protocols="any"
  http-service-ssl-require-authentication="false"
  http-service-ssl-truststore=""
  http-service-ssl-truststore-password=""
  jmx-manager="true" ***(wanted "false")***
  jmx-manager-access-file=""
  jmx-manager-bind-address=""
  jmx-manager-hostname-for-clients=""
  jmx-manager-http-port="7070"
  jmx-manager-password-file=""
  jmx-manager-port="1099"
  jmx-manager-ssl-ciphers="any"
  jmx-manager-ssl-enabled="false"
  jmx-manager-ssl-keystore=""
  jmx-manager-ssl-keystore-password=""
  jmx-manager-ssl-keystore-type=""
  jmx-manager-ssl-protocols="any"
  jmx-manager-ssl-require-authentication="true"
  jmx-manager-ssl-truststore=""
  jmx-manager-ssl-truststore-password=""
  jmx-manager-start="false"
  jmx-manager-update-rate="2000"
  load-cluster-configuration-from-dir="false"
  locator-wait-time="0"
  locators="192.168.1.101[13334]" ***(wanted "")***
  lock-memory="false"
  log-disk-space-limit="0"
  log-file="locator1.log" ***(wanted "server1.log")***
  log-file-size-limit="0"
  log-level="config"
  max-num-reconnect-tries="3"
  max-wait-time-reconnect="60000"
  mcast-address="/239.192.81.1"
  mcast-flow-control="1048576, 0.25, 5000"
  mcast-port="0"
  mcast-recv-buffer-size="1048576"
  mcast-send-buffer-size="65535"
  mcast-ttl="32"
  member-timeout="5000"
  membership-port-range="[1024,65535]"
  memcached-bind-address=""
  memcached-port="0"
  memcached-protocol="ASCII"
  name="locator1" ***(wanted "server1")***
  off-heap-memory-size=""
  redis-bind-address=""
  redis-password=""
  redis-port="0"
  redundancy-zone=""
  remote-locators=""
  remove-unresponsive-client="false"
  roles=""
  security-client-accessor=""
  security-client-accessor-pp=""
  security-client-auth-init=""
  security-client-authenticator=""
  security-client-dhalgo=""
  security-log-file=""
  security-log-level="config"
  security-manager=""
  security-peer-auth-init=""
  security-peer-authenticator=""
  security-peer-verifymember-timeout="1000"
  security-post-processor=""
  security-shiro-init=""
  security-udp-dhalgo=""
  server-bind-address=""
  server-ssl-ciphers="any"
  server-ssl-enabled="false"
  server-ssl-keystore=""
  server-ssl-keystore-password=""
  server-ssl-keystore-type=""
  server-ssl-protocols="any"
  server-ssl-require-authentication="true"
  server-ssl-truststore=""
  server-ssl-truststore-password=""
  socket-buffer-size="32768"
  socket-lease-time="60000"
  ssl-ciphers="any"
  ssl-cluster-alias=""
  ssl-default-alias=""
  ssl-enabled-components="[]"
  ssl-gateway-alias=""
  ssl-jmx-alias=""
  ssl-keystore=""
  ssl-keystore-password=""
  ssl-keystore-type=""
  ssl-locator-alias=""
  ssl-protocols="any"
  ssl-require-authentication="true"
  ssl-server-alias=""
  ssl-truststore=""
  ssl-truststore-password=""
  ssl-web-alias=""
  ssl-web-require-authentication="false"
  start-dev-rest-api="false"
  start-locator=""
  statistic-archive-file=""
  statistic-sample-rate="1000"
  statistic-sampling-enabled="true"
  tcp-port="0"
  udp-fragment-size="60000"
  udp-recv-buffer-size="1048576"
  udp-send-buffer-size="65535"
  use-cluster-configuration="true"
  user-command-packages=""

  at org.apache.geode.distributed.internal.InternalDistributedSystem.validateSameProperties(InternalDistributedSystem.java:2906)
at org.apache.geode.distributed.DistributedSystem.connect(DistributedSystem.java:193)
at org.apache.geode.cache.CacheFactory.create(CacheFactory.java:210)
at org.apache.geode.distributed.internal.DefaultServerLauncherCacheProvider.createCache(DefaultServerLauncherCacheProvider.java:52)
at org.apache.geode.distributed.ServerLauncher.createCache(ServerLauncher.java:860)
at org.apache.geode.distributed.ServerLauncher.start(ServerLauncher.java:772)
at demo.Application.serverStarter(Application.java:25)
at demo.Application.main(Application.java:9)
  WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
  WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.geode.internal.shared.NativeCalls (file:/C:/Users/Fatih%20Barmanbay/.m2/repository/org/apache/geode/geode-core/1.2.1/geode-core-1.2.1.jar) to field java.lang.ProcessEnvironment.theCaseInsensitiveEnvironment
  WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.geode.internal.shared.NativeCalls
  WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
  WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

What is causing this error and how do I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you start the server, add `start-locator` property to start an embedded locator within the server process. More about the property in docs.

```
ServerLauncher serverLauncher = new ServerLauncher.Builder()
        .setMemberName("server1")
        .setServerPort(40404)
        **.set("start-locator", "address[port1]")**
        .build();
    serverLauncher.start();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. For those who get stuck with the same problem can solve the issue by starting locator, server and client in different java processes (start each in it's own main function or java project)